# How to Hide a Particular website page URL from Search engines?

Tags: php, .htaccess, meta-tags

1. My project is an E-commerce website that It contains lot of static and dynamic pages. I want to hide *only* one page from Search engines. If any one search that text then it need not display on search engine like "Google","Yahoo" etc.

> **http://www.mysitename.com/users/download/id**

The above url need to hide in search engines.

If any one searching my mysitename then above link also displaying in Google search as of now. what i can do for this ?

Comment: If you need to stop search engines indexing it, then the `robots.txt` solution is fine. If, however, there's a security issue with people randomly arriving at this page, it will not be adequate - and in fact the presence of the file's name in your `robots.txt` could point out this page to malicious users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a file `robots.txt` in your website root directory with the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /users/download/id
```

This approach basically tells the Search Engine not to index `/users/download/id`.

This doesn't mean every Search Engine will do that, but most of the modern Search Engines will take in consideration that file.

Comment: Using robots.txt does _not_ help if you want to hide a page from search engine results. With robots.txt, you only tell search engines not to index content and not to show a snippet, but the URL can still be listed.

Comment: Can I have a support for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943061/block-some-of-dynamic-pages-from-search-engines Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Seo technique...

There is code you can put into your HTML which will prevent the bots from spidering your page(s). This code is put in the header of your web page(s) (meaning between the  and  tags), in the form of a meta tag (and you thought meta tags were for keywords only).

Here are four examples of how this code will look;

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive,nosnippet,noodp" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive,nosnippet,noodp" />
```