# Block some of dynamic pages from search engines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, search-engine, googlebot

I need to block some of my pages from search engines.How can I do that ?
App has been developed by using ASP.net MVC and AngularJS. Thanks in advance.

These are the urls which I want to block from the search engines.

```
http://localhost:12534/myurl123-event?participant=12957

http://localhost:12534/myurl123-event
```

**Note :** The last part of the url is **dynamic** (i.e. `myurl123-event?participant=12957` and `myurl123-event`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a robots.txt with a disallow setting:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /myurl123-event
```

If you want to block everything, then you can use

```
Disallow: /*
```

or you can put all your dynamic pages inside a route (or use the controller name, if you're routing is straightforward controller/method/id)

```
Disallow: /dynamic/
```

Comment: But my urls are dynamic.So how can I do that on such scenarios ?

Comment: Exactly this. Also, if the `123` part is dynamic, a wildcard should work (using `*`, something like `/myurl*`). Good crawlers will respect it, and if one's trying to prevent _all_ crawlers (i.e. ones that don't respect robots.txt), they're going to have a very hard time.

Comment: @DRobinson Actually whole url is dynamic i.e `myurl123-event`.So can I do that ? Do I need to use `regex` or something like that ?

Comment: Could you explain little bit more about the 3rd option (dynamic pages inside a route)? How can I use it with my dynamic urls ?

Answer (score 1):

The Google preferred way is to use canonical links:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://somedomain.com/myurl123-event" />`

This tag's function is to tell the search engine what URL should be indexed on these pages containing dynamic querystring params.

See more about them here:  [Google link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Using these you wont have to worry about accidentally blacklisting part of your site, such as with using robots.txt files and taking a hit on your traffic.

Comment: Can I do this with dynamic urls as well ?

Comment: These  link tags go in the header of the page containing all the optional dynamic querystring params and it tells the search engine which URL you prefer. So... yes? Check the link for more details.